# How to boot QNX on x86 system from USB drive?

Tags: x86, operating-system, qnx, usb-flash-drive

I downloaded and built the (generic) QNX BSP and copied it on a flash drive. The target is a x86 system. The problem now is that the bios does not recognise the flash drive / bsp and therefore cannot boot the OS. Is there some trick I forgot? Please ask further questions if you need more information! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at http://community.qnx.com/sf/wiki/do/viewPage/projects.bsp/wiki/X86Bios and download the user guide. There is a chapter describing how to boot from USB devices. I have already tried it and it works.

Answer (score -1):

This QNX nowledge base entry might also be helpful:

http://www.qnx.com/support/knowledgebase.html?id=50130000000Smi2

Here's a simple procedure that can get you going quickly:

1. From a native QNX system go to /boot/build
2. Build a default OS image: mkifs bios.build bios.ifs
3. Create a partition on the card or USB stick if there isn't one yet like this:

`# fdisk /dev/<device name>`

Create a partition of type 77,78 or 79 and make it bootable.

4. Initialize the partition and copy the image to it:
   dinit -hq -f /boot/build/bios.ifs /dev/t
5. Install the loaders:
   dloader /dev/hd10 pc1
   dloader /dev/hd10t77 pc2
   Reboot the system and the card should boot.